# Adding systemPath for jar file inside pom.xml dependency tag

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have imported an existing maven project into eclipse IDE. The pom.xml have a dependency looking like below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myApp</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyDBConn</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/dependencies/MyDBConn.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

In the line

```
<systemPath>${basedir}/dependencies/MyDBConn.jar</systemPath>
```

I am getting an error saying

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
> - 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.myApp:MyDBConn:jar should not point at files
> within the project directory, ${basedir}/dependencies/MultiDBConn.jar will be unresolvable by dependent
> projects
> - 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.myApp:MyDBConn:jar must specify an absolute
> path but is ${basedir}/dependencies/MyDBConn.jar

I have MyDBConn.jar file in dependencies folder inside the project directory. In my understanding ${basedir} points to the path where pom.xml is located.
Why am i getting this error then?

Comment: First question: Why do you need the system scope dependency? Is that dependency build by Maven or not?

Comment: there are sometimes reasons for systempath imports. same here. maven build from terminal works fine. in my case this is just eclipse ide, pom opened with pom editor and the editor is showing it as an error. so i guess it is an editor bug. unfortunately the project im project explorer is also marked as failing

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error; it is a warning. Please check the logs again. Maven is warning you that the dependency `MyDBConn.jar` will not be available to other projects that depend on this project (the one that depends on `MyDBConn.jar`).

Is `com.myApp.MyDBConn` something you wrote? You can run `mvn clean install` on that project to place the jar in your local Maven repository. Then, you can use it like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyDBConn</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's also very important to note that Maven team says system dependencies are [deprecated](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#system-dependencies).

Comment: the build from command line is ok. it is just the pom editor in eclipse which marks it as an error.